# Calculations between matrices in r

Tags: r, matrix, calculation

I have a question related to working on two matrices.

Let's assume that first matrix (P(i)) is:

```
x <- rmultinom(2, size = 10, prob=c(0.5,0.5))

> x
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    4
[2,]    4    6
```

..and the second matrix (Q(i)) is:

```
y <- rmultinom(2, size = 10, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
> y
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    7
[2,]    4    3
```

Let's assume that P(i) stands for every cell in the first matrix and Q(i) stands for every cell in the second matrix. I am trying to sum this function, (I could not find the symbol for the "Sum"):

```
z = (Sum)(P(i)*log(P(i)/Q(i)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `sum(x*(log(x/y)))`

Comment: The expected output is a value greater than 0. I am expecting it to be small something like 0.01. But more importantly, I want to do this calculation for the same cells (i.e. P1x1 and Q1x1) across the matrices and sum them up. Is that clear?